# Sharing a Zip File

Tags: swift, xcode, file, share

I have a file named `airdropme.zip` to be included in my app bundle that I want to make available for sharing using AirDrop. The function below brings up a dialog with the filename showing, but when I share it the file that is transferred not a valid zip archive; it is not `airdropme.zip`. I have tried placing airdropme.zip in the `Assets.xcassets` folder but that doesn't work. Where do I put  `airdropme.zip` and how do I change the function so that it lets me share `airdropme.zip` with AirDrop when called?

```
@IBAction func airdropMyFile() {
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "airdropme.zip")
        var filesToShare = [Any]()
        filesToShare.append(fileURL)
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: filesToShare , applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

The function does not find the file in the `Assets.xcassets` folder.

Answer (score 2):

If the zip file is in your app's resource bundle then you get its URL as follows:

```
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "airdropme", withExtension: "zip")!
```

It's fine to force-unwrap the result because it will never fail once you get it working in development. If that line crashes during development then it means the `airdropme.zip` file isn't ending up in your app's resource bundle. Go to your target's "Build Phases" and look under the "Copy Bundle Resources" section and make sure the `airdropme.zip` file is listed.

Your posted code now becomes:

```
@IBAction func airdropMyFile() {
    let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "airdropme", withExtension: "zip")!
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileURL], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Also note that there's no reason to `NSURL` in Swift. Use `URL`.

FYI - when you try to create a `URL` (or `NSURL`) with a file path, you should pass a fully qualified file path, not just a file name. There's no assumption that the file is found in some current working directory.